# How to write down sign of a constant that has maximal absolute value from a tuple?

Tags: education

I have a problem where I am taking the sign of a constant that has maximal value in absolute value from a tuple. I need to know how to write this as a formula.

I saw it written in a book as follows, however I don't think that's a proper way, hence this is going to be always positive, right?

$value=sign(h),\ where \ h=max(\left|c1\right|,\left|c2\right|)$

It's a silly question, but I can't find some elegant way to write it.

Comment: The way you wrote it, $value=1$, since $h$ is a positive number....

Comment: oh..I knew it's silly. I had it programmed in python in this way. Thanks!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that what the book has written is *not* correct. You could get what you want this way:

`t = (c1,c2)`

`h = argmax(|t|)`

where by $|t|$ we mean the absolute value of each item in $t$. Now,

`value = sign(t[h])`